# If $E^\ast=E\cup\{Δ\}$ is the one-point compactification of $E$ and $x:[0,\infty)\to E^\ast$ is right-continuous, is $\inf\{t\ge0:x(t)=Δ\}$ attained?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, continuity, compactification

Let

- $(E,\tau)$ be a topological space and $\Delta\not\in E$;
- $E^\ast:=E\cup\{\Delta\}$ and $$\tau^\ast:=\tau\cup\underbrace{\left\{E^\ast\setminus B:B\subseteq E\text{ is }\tau\text{-closed and }\tau\text{-compact}\right\}}_{=:\:\mathcal C}.$$
- $x:[0,\infty)\to E^\ast$ be right-continuous and $$\zeta:=\inf\underbrace{\left\{t\ge0:x(t)=\Delta\right\}}_{=:\:I}.$$

> Are we able to show that either
>
> - $I=\emptyset$ and hence $\zeta=\infty$;
> - $\zeta\in I$ and hence $x(\zeta)=\Delta$.

I know that if $(M,d)$ is a metric space, $f:[0,\infty)\to M$ is right-continuous, $B\subseteq M$ is $d$-closed and $$\rho:=\inf\underbrace{\left\{t\ge0:f(t)\in B\right\}}_{=:\:J},$$ then either

- $J=\emptyset$ and hence $\rho=\infty$;
- $\rho\in J$ and hence $f(\rho)\in B$.

> However, I've got trouble to show the same in the setting described in my question. I'm willing to assume that $\tau$ is metrizable, but I'm not sure whether this helpful at all. (I don't even know if this implies that $\tau^\ast$ is metrizable as well; I guess not?!)

Comment: Do you mean $x(\zeta) = \Delta$?

Comment: @KritikerderElche Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Noting that $E$ is open in $E^*$ (which is equivalent to $\{\Delta\}$ being closed in $E^*$), this follows from the more general

**Theorem.** Let $Z$ be any topological space and $z_0 \in Z$ be a point such that $\{z_0\}$ is closed in $Z$. Moreover, let $x : [0,\infty) \to Z$ be right-continuous, $I = \{ t \ge 0 \mid x(t) = z_0\} = x^{-1}(z_0)$ and $\zeta = \inf I$. Then **either** $I = \emptyset$ (and hence $\zeta = \infty$) **or** $\zeta \in I$ (and hence $x(\zeta) = z_0$).

Proof. Clearly either $I = \emptyset$ (which implies $\zeta = \inf \emptyset = \infty$) or $I \ne \emptyset$. Let us show that in the latter case we have $\zeta \in I$. Assume that $\zeta \notin I$. Then $x(\zeta) \in U = Z \setminus \{z_0\}$. Since $U$ is open and $x$ is right-continuous at $\zeta$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x((\zeta,\zeta+\delta)) \subset U$. Thus $(\zeta,\zeta+\delta) \cap I = \emptyset$, hence $\zeta = \inf I \ge\zeta +\delta$ (recall the assumption $\zeta \notin I$) which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With *any space*, I guess you mean *any topological space*, right? If so, don't we need to assume that the topology on $Z$ is Hausdorff in order to ensure that limit points of nets (hence sequences) are unique?

Comment: And just to be sure: How do you define right-continuity of a function $x:[0,\infty)\to Z$ at a point $t\ge0$? My definition is that for every neighborhood $N$ of $x(t)$, there is a $\delta>0$ with $x((t,t+\delta))\subseteq N$. This should be enough to conclude using your argumentation.

Comment: Yes, *space* means *topological space* and we have the same understanding of  right continuity. But you are right, we need more assumptions on $(Z,z_0)$ to conclude that $x(\zeta) = z_0$. I shall make an update.

Comment: Would be great if you could provide an update of your answer! (Do you think Hausdorfness is not enough? What I thought is that if, more generall, $\zeta=\inf\{t\ge0:x(t)\in B\}$ for some $B\subseteq Z$, we need that $B$ is closed in order to ensure that $x(\zeta)\in B$ (if $\zeta<\infty$, of course))

Comment: @0xbadf00d Update available.

Comment: Thank you for the update! WIth "which means $y$ is continuous" you actually mean continuous at $\zeta$, right?

Comment: But then I don't get how you conclude that $y^{-1}(\{z_0\})$ is closed in $[\zeta,\infty)$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I made another update and hope it is clear now.

Comment: Thank you. It's clear now.

Comment: It's worth noting that your proof even shows that the claim is true when $\{z_0\}$ is replaced by an arbitrary closed $B\subseteq Z$.